Import cell value to script Autofill
I am working on trying to automate the length of an autofill based on the value in cell C6. The cell C6 looks at row 9 and finds the last instance column where there is a value with the following formula
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,LOOKUP(1E+307,COLUMN(9:9)*IF(9:9="","",1)),4),"1", "")
I have the following code linked to the button:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();


//part that isnt working
Dim val as Long
val = Range("C6").Value


    // Auto fill range
        selectedSheet.getRange("D11:D26").autoFill("D11:'val'26"), ExcelScript.AutoFillType.fillDefault;
}


I would like the script to pull the value from C6 which will be a column lettering that is 3 leters, such as MXT and insert it where i have typed 'val' in the auto fill section.
I tried to use:
Dim val as Long
val = Range("C6").Value

And val as my variable in the autofill portion.

It’s typescript, not VBA, you probably need to educate yourself on the language you’re dealing with. Have you read any doco? Not trying to be smart, it’s probably a good idea to look into that though.

Get the content of cell C6 with getText() and use D11:${val}26 as autofilling range.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

  const val: string = selectedSheet.getRange("C6").getText();
  
  // Auto fill range
  selectedSheet.getRange("D11:D26").autoFill(`D11:${val}26`, ExcelScript.AutoFillType.fillDefault);
}

Microsoft documentation:

ExcelScript.Range getText() interface

